# Do 2 bachelor's degrees look bad for PhD admissions?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, application, undergraduate

I am currently doing my second bachelor's degree after having gotten very sick towards the end of my first and not being able to take the classes that I wanted, or the sufficient research experience for a PhD. Does this look damningly bad for graduate admissions? I am also a little bit older and my grades towards the end of my first degree aren't so great (went from a 3.95 to a 3.2). Sorry in advance if this is a silly question, but I'm pretty nervous and don't know where else to look.

Comment: Best of luck to you Albert! Stay well, and in the meantime consider sharing what these two majors are and which area, if you currently have one in mind, you’re eyeing for graduate work.

Comment: Thank you so much! My first degree was in Computer Science and my second is in Mathematics & Statistics. I'm broadly interested in probability & information theory, and am currently excited by the theoretical foundations of deep learning and cryptography, although I can't pick between the two yet!

Comment: What will you do with the answer? Since you're already doing it, are you going to stop? Or are you asking whether you should even apply?

Comment: I think I'd try regardless but just wanted to see if I'm being delusional, or if I should lower my expectations for where to apply just given my history.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing inherently problematic about getting two degrees. There is certainly nothing problematic about getting sick.  You appear to have went back to school a second time so the first is only loosely relevant.

One should not be generally concerned about "extra" education when you are going for a PhD. (I have met people with multiple PhD's in different subject areas.) Perhaps if you had 3 or 4 undergraduate degrees I may wonder about the intensity of the programs or if you were better served by outside activities/internships - but this can all be explained with a good letter.